# Binary to Decimal Converter GUI JAVA

Tags: java

I've tried to finish my program but it cannot convert to binary what do you think is the problem? if I press convert it would simple run a script saying, string index is out of range on how many digits of the binary. and if so how would I improve the codes. Thank you for the ones who would comment to this thread :>

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BinaryGUI extends BinaryGUIDemo {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new BinaryGUI();
        }

        private JFrame frame;
        private JButton button;
        private JTextField text;
        private JTextField text2;
        private String decimalnumber = null;

        public BinaryGUI() {
            frame = new JFrame("Conversion!");

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Binary:");
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.add(label);

            text = new JTextField(15);
            frame.add(text);

            JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Decimal:");
            frame.add(label2);

            text2 = new JTextField(15);
            frame.add(text2);

            
            button = new JButton("Convert");
            button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
            frame.add(button);
            
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(250, 300);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void Convert() {
            String binary = text.getText();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
                char select = binary.charAt(binary.length() - i);
                char number = (char) (select * Math.pow(2, i));
                decimalnumber += number;
            }
        }

        public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Convert();
                if (button.getText().equals("Convert")) {
                    text2.setText(decimalnumber);
                    text.getText();
                    text2.getText();
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We can use [`Integer::toBinaryString`](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/17/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) in order to convert an `int` to its binary representation.

Comment: where would i put the toBinaryString?

Comment: Think about what happens when `i = 0`, then you try to access the String with `charAt(binary.length())` which is out of range. You need to add `-1` in order to prevent the out of range error.

Comment: NB method names begin lower case in Java: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions

Comment: Binary to decimal? or convert to binary? Which is it?

Comment: your question is all about converting binary String to number.
also, @Mushroomator explained your algorithm issue.

Comment: when I press convert it does not convert the binary to decimal vice versa

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

##### Index ouf of bounds

When using `str.charAt()` you can only have indices between `0` inclusive and `str.length - 1` inclusive, meaning that `str.charAt(str.length)` will result in an out of bounds error. To prevent that use `binary.length() - i - 1` instead of `binary.length() - i`.

##### Type-casting to `char`

What you do in this line `char number = (char) (select * Math.pow(2, i));` doesn't make any sense. You want to have an `int` returned not a `char`. `select` is a `char` here and doesn't hold the value `0` or `1` as you seem to think it does. Also `Math.pow()` is unnecessary here, you can just use a [bit-shift](https://www.interviewcake.com/concept/java/bit-shift) which will be faster and prevent unnecessary type casts.

##### Ignore `0` bits

As I've pointed out before `select` hold the chars `'0'` and `'1'` which don't translate to `0` and `1` integers as you seem to think. Therefore your calculation with `select * Math.pow(2, i)` yields unexpected results. Instead you could just use an `if` condition checking whether a char is `'0'`. This way you also save an expensive multiplication operation.

As you only index the individual chars of the String you could just transform everything to a `char` array.

Here an implementation showing how to convert from a binary string to a decimal number. It also shows how you can use `Integer::toBinaryString()` to convert in the opposite direction.

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convBinaryStringToInt("1001"));
        System.out.println(convBinaryStringToInt("0001"));
        System.out.println(convBinaryStringToInt("0010"));
        System.out.println(convBinaryStringToInt("0011"));

        // convert the other way round
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(9));
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1));
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(2));
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(3));
    }

    public static int convBinaryStringToInt(String binary) {
        int decimalNumber = 0;
        var bits = binary.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
            // add -1 otherwise you will run out of bounds
            char bit = bits[bits.length - i - 1];
            // skip zeros
            if(bit == '0') continue;
            // now we know we have a one bit, instead of using Math.pow() we can just bit shift which is faster and
            // prevents unnecessary type casting
            // shift 1 bit to left
            int number = 1 << i;
            decimalNumber += number;
        }
        return decimalNumber;
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
9
1
2
3
1001
1
10
11
```

Comment: I have resolved the out of bounds issues and now I cant recall how to fix the 2nd and 3rd issue

Comment: Well, the line `if(bit == '0') continue;` resolves issue #2 and the bit-shift `int number = 1 << i;` resolve issue #3. `select` in your code contains the ASCII value of `'0'` or `'1'` (see output of `System.out.println((int)'0');`) and you will see that the `int` value of `'0'` is not `0`, hence your multiplication with `selected * Math.pow(2, i)` will not be `0` if `selected = '0'`.

Comment: public void Convert() {
   String binary = text.getText();
   var bits = binary.toCharArray();
         for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
          char select = binary.charAt(binary.length() - i - 1);
             if(select == '0') continue;
             int number = 1 << i;
             decimalnumber += number;
         }
     }. Would these be correct?

Comment: And it prints null+randomnumbers when converted into decimal

Comment: when it gets to 4 digit binary it generates more than the said binary

Comment: What do you initialize `decimalnumber` to? It should be `0`. It is ẃorking for me. Which string exactly do you have as an input, what does it return and what do you expect it to return?

Answer (score 0):

**CODE FOR CONVERTING**
this is what I used in converting binary to decimal. but instead of getting decimal it prints out null+decimal and the maximum binary numbers that it could read is 2 binary number example: Binary:111 when converted to decimal it prints out Null24 which is 11000 in binary that's the problem. When getting big binary numbers 8 digits it explodes and I dont know how to fix this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BinaryGUI extends BinaryGUIDemo {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new BinaryGUI();
             
            int n;
            String numInput;
            String binary;
            numInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a number:");
            n = Integer.parseInt(numInput);
     
             binary  = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Binary equivalent is: " +binary);
        }

        private JFrame frame;
        private JButton button;
        private JTextField text;
        private JTextField text2;
        private String decimalnumber = null;

        public BinaryGUI() {
            
            frame = new JFrame("Conversion!");

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Binary:");
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.add(label);

            text = new JTextField(15);
            frame.add(text);

            JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Decimal:");
            frame.add(label2);

            text2 = new JTextField(15);
            frame.add(text2);

            
            button = new JButton("Convert");
            button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
            frame.add(button);
            
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(250, 300);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void Convert() {
            String binary = text.getText();
            var bits = binary.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 1; i < bits.length; i++) {
                char select = binary.charAt(binary.length() - i - 1);
                if(select == '0') continue;
                int number = 1 << i;
                decimalnumber += number;
            }
        }
        public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Convert();
                if (button.getText().equals("Convert")) {
                    text2.setText(decimalnumber);
                    text.getText();
                    text2.getText();
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You define `decimalnumber` as a `String` hence `+` means String concatenation (`+` is an overloaded operator in Java). You should declare `decimalnumber` as an `int` and `+` will mean summation. Also try to use local variables instead of global ones. Declare `decimalNumber` in `Convert()` and let `Convert()` return something. It would also be better to make it `static` with a parameter and use lower case at beginning.

And please not that answers are reserved for answers only. Please edit your question if you have something to add or ask another question if you have another question.

Comment: when I declare `int decimalnumber = 0;` it does not convert binary to decimal

Comment: still when change `public static int convert()` it still does not read the program even though I declared `int decimalnumber = 0; ` yes, it removed the null but it did not convert binary into decimal

Comment: You have set `i = 1` hence you are skipping the first iteration in your implementation which may result in wrong conversions when there is a `1`-bit at the last position. Please have a look at my solution and compare yours line-by-line. Whenever you find something that is different to your solution think about why and whether that might impact the correctness of the solution. I can't do more for you then giving you a working solution and explaining how it works. You should be able to copy/ paste and compare. It's just 9 lines of code.

Comment: I copy/pasted your codes in my java compiler when run it says here that `cannot invoke "String.toCharArray()" because "Binary" is null`

Comment: Then make sure the parameter `binary` is not `null`. `var binaryStr = text.getText();
        if(binaryStr != null){
            convBinaryStringToInt(binaryStr);
        } `.

Comment: public static int convert(String binary) {
int decimalNumber = 0;
var binaryStr = text.getText();
var bits = binary.toCharArray();
if(binaryStr != null){
convert(binaryStr);
}
for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
char bit = bits[bits.length - i - 1];
if(bit == '0') continue;
int number = 1 << i;
decimalNumber += number;
}
return decimalNumber;
} this is the current code and when i press convert it still shows the same error.